# How to sort a List after Jackson deserializes?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Match {
     List<InningDetail> innings;
}
```

I would like to sort the `innings` like this:

```
   Collections.sort(innings, new Comparator<InningDetail>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(InningDetail lhs, InningDetail rhs) {
           return lhs.getInningsNo() > rhs.getInningsNo() ? 0 : 1;
       }
   });
```

How to perform the sort post the deserialization?

Comment: This `compare` implementation doesn't look correct. Might throw an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`. Also it is unclear to me, what your current problem is. You call for deserialization somewhere in your code, so there shouldn't be a problem to sort after that.

Comment: No, I don't call deserialization. Jackson does that. I am looking for Jackson helpers/annotations that can post-process items after deserialization.

Comment: Jackson does that? Automatically? Without any method call from your side?

Comment: @Tom, I'll fix the sort method later. That is not the actual question here :)

Comment: @Tom I am using Jackson via Retrofit. Post All API calls, the response JSON is serialized into a class.